# Failing to Start gunicorn.service using systemd

Tags: 18.04, systemd, services, nginx, sockets

## **gunicorn.socket**

```
[Unit]  
Description=gunicorn socket

[Socket]  
ListenStream=/run/gunicorn.sock

[Install]  
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

## **gunicorn.service**

```
[Unit]  
Description=gunicorn daemon
Requires=gunicorn.socket
After=network.target

[Service]    
PIDFile=/run/gunicorn/pid  

User=ubuntu  

Group=www-data  

RuntimeDirectory=gunicorn  

WorkingDirectory=~/Python-Projects  

ExecStart=~/Python-Projects/myvenv/bin/gunicorn \  
          --access-logfile ~/Python-Projects/djangoTest/logs/djangoTest.access.log \  
          --error-logfile ~/Python-Projects/djangoTest/logs/djangoTest.error.log \  
          --pid /run/gunicorn/pid   \  
          --env DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=djangoTest.settings.production \  
          --bind unix:/run/gunicorn.sock \  
          djangoTest.wsgi:application

ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID  

ExecStop=/bin/kill -s TERM $MAINPID  

PrivateTmp=true  


[Install]    
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

### **My Project Directory**

- djangoTest(MyTest Django Project)
- manage.py
- myvenv(My virtualEnv - has gunicorn and Django and other dependencies)
- static

## **DjangoTest Tree**

```
djangoTest  
├── __init__.py  
├── __pycache__  
│   ├── __init__.cpython-36.pyc  
│   ├── settings.cpython-36.pyc  
│   ├── urls.cpython-36.pyc  
│   └── wsgi.cpython-36.pyc  
├── settings.py  
├── urls.py  
└── wsgi.py
```

I am using the below tutorial for setting up the same. 
[https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu-18-04#creating-systemd-socket-and-service-files-for-gunicorn][1]

When I am starting the gunicorn service using below command

**sudo systemctl status gunicorn.socket**

I am getting the below error

```
**Jan 03 06:01:47 ip-# systemd[1]: **gunicorn.socket: Socket service gunicorn.service not loaded, refusing.**  
Jan 03 06:01:47 ip-# systemd[1]: **Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.  
root@ip-#:/etc/systemd/system# Jan 03 04:56:52 ip-# systemd[1]: Failed to listen on gunicorn socket.****
```

PLEASE HELP!!

Answer (score 1):

I am able to resolve this issue now. I have changed configurations in the gunicorn.service file in the below properties.

WorkingDirectory=~/Python-Projects  to /root/Python-Projects

Comment: Results in a formatting error. `Failed to restart gunicorn.service: Unit gunicorn.service is not loaded properly: Exec format error.` It's caused by the `~`